# Storing dynamic user created HTML tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, html-table

I am developing a platform for users to create a table and enter whatever information they like in it.

For example:

```
Name  | Date | Award       |
-----------------------------
James | 2013 | Best person |
...   | ...  | ...
```

etc... However the user can create as many table headings (columns) and entries (rows) as they want. So one table could have three headings then 30 rows, and other could have 2 headings and 5 rows etc.

Now I am trying to set up my database accordingly, to account for this. The only options that I can think of would be **(a) to store the HTML of the table into the database and output it that way. Or (b) create a table in MySQL for the headings and then another table for the rows but I am not completely sure how to accomplish this.**

What would be the best solution for this? All responses are welcome.

Comment: Do you store text as html-table or MySQL Data?

Comment: I store data as MySQL Data

Comment: I'm not following. Please can you explain more?

Comment: HTML is a text based data but MYSQL-data is completely different, I don't encounter relation between both, I need to understand your goal to give you and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Create the tables via JavaScript and jQuery

b) present them to the user by HTML

c) store all required information as a JavaScript variable (Object)

d) Use [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) to convert the variable in a string

e) If you use one send the string to your Server and store it as a String in a database or in a file (e.g. via WebSockets)

f) You can store the user-Input in the users [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) as well